# Are iOS "views" and HTML divs similar?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I found that placing a view in my app and sizing it to my needs is pretty similar to divs in HTML. Should I be using them this way?

Here's an example of a place I want to use a view.

[image]

I want to fill that in, should I be using a view here? or something more semantical?

End result with a view:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to fill the entire top with the blue color? The navbar should be filled automatically...

Comment: @RashwanL I'm trying set the status bar to have a blue background in this case. But in general if I want to place just a rectangle somewhere would a view be a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a rectangle somewhere you could definitely use an `UIView()`, If you´re using your storyboard make sure to set the right constraint and if you´re doing it programmatically you could do the following to get it work with all phone sizes:

Swift 3.0:

```
let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds

let anotherView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screen.width, height: 45))
anotherView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
view.addSubview(anotherView)
```

Swift 2.x:

```
let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

let anotherView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screen.width, height: 45))
anotherView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
view.addSubview(anotherView)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!